# How do I allocate memory by using new in C++?

Tags: c++, new-operator, dynamic-allocation

I have following static declaration of memory:

```
void* array[5000];
```

How I can allocate the same memory using `operator new` in C++?

Comment: What exactly do you want to allocate?

Comment: @kalyan: I fail to see how this question isn't suitable for SO. Many novices get a bit lost when the solution entails a double-pointer, and I'm not sure that Google would be all that helpful to a novice.

Comment: How is this not a decent SO question? It's how to turn a static allocation into a dynamic one (for many, it's not obvious that you need to add an extra `*` in the declaration in addition to how the `new` needs to be used with pointer).

Comment: How is that localized? There's *tons* of C/C++-specific questions on here.

Comment: @moderators: please abstain from such heavy-handed nuclear history revisions as the remaining rubble indicates has been done here.

Comment: Hah, true, it now looks like Marcelo and I are talking to a ghost. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
void **array = new void*[5000];
```

Comment: Yeah, the voids were enough to confuse me because my original answer (before your edit) actually compiled! Then I realized it was wrong and deleted it.

Comment: Not to mention that I edited it wrong.. I deleted an asterisk instead of adding one. :)

Answer (score -2):

at  above there is array of pointers 
here is just an array of Integer.

int array  = new int [5000];

Comment: i want an void* array, not a int array.

Comment: Not only that, this is not C++ syntax.